# Trying to Create dynamic laravel query string but getting error

Tags: laravel, builder

```
$string='->get()';
$data_asset=DB::table('assets').$string;
```

`Object` of `class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` could not be converted to `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got something similar to what you're trying to achieve.

In your code, your $data_asset=DB::table('assets') returns a QueryBuilder, which builds a string in the background with your query parameters.

To do what you're after:

```
    // Create a QueryBuilder instance with a table
    $q = DB::table('users');

    // I actually set this elsewhere, but for this example I've set it here
    $params = ['email'=>'joe.bloggs@example.com','toSql'=>true];

    // Use the QueryBuilder instance again, specifying a criteria
    $q->where('users.email', '=', $params['email']);

    if ( isset($params['toSql']) ):
        // Returns my query as it's full SQL string (minus parameters)
        return $q->toSql();
    else:
        // Returns a Collection
        return $q->get();
    endif;
```

This allows you to build a dynamic QueryBuilder builder.

Comment: I solved it like this(   $q->orWhere($column,$operator,$txt);$data_asset=$q->get();)thanks a lot mate,it worked out fine for me like charm.